# AlarmManager and Service - Starting several services?

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

I want to accomplish to spawn a service every hour. This service should perform some SQL database operations. In order to do so, I've used AlarmManager like this:

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, DeleteCaseService.class);
 PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(Home.this, 0, intent, 0);
 AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 60*60*1000, pintent);
```

I haven't made the code for the service yet, but that's not the problem. My problem is kinda theoretical. If you imagine this app running for 8 hours constantly, will there will be started 8 different Service in 8 different threads? Or when will a service get killed? Is this the best approach? Feel free to suggest other solutions, but I want to keep the `AlarmManager`

Thanks.

Comment: These days, you'll probably want to use WorkManager for this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using service use broadcast receiver for making background operation on database
to call the broadcast receiver use the bellow code

```
public class AlarmMgnr
    {
        private Intent intent;
        Context context;
        private static AlarmManager aMgnr;
        private static PendingIntent sender;

        public AlarmMgnr(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public void registerAlarm()
        {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

            int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);

            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

            System.out.println("AlarmMgnr.registerAlarm()");

            intent = new Intent(context, <YourReciverCalssName>.class);

            sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            aMgnr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            // aMgnr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, sender);
            aMgnr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 180000L, sender);
            // aMgnr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 60000L, sender);
        }

        public void unregisterAlarm()
        {
            aMgnr.cancel(sender);
        }

    }
}
```

And start this alaram manage once only when application got installed .